# How to implement retry FTT in cloudsim using No optimization algorithm?

Tags: cloud, fault-tolerance, cloudsim

[image: Please help me in modifying algorithm for retry]

Please help me in modifying algorithm for retry? is this algorithm makes sense ? Is it ok our need changes ? plz guide ?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, make sure you are familiar with the [`CloudletScheduler`](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/CloudletScheduler.java) class and how it works. You can study the [`CloudletSchedulerTimeShared`](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/CloudletSchedulerTimeShared.java) scheduler and how it is used in [CloudSimExample3](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample3.java).

Once you understand how that works, you can implement your own `CloudletScheduler` using the logic of the pseudo-algorithm described in your question.

Comment: Thank Thiago Sa ... i have written algorithm for retry FTT by my own.As in retry FTT failed task are restart from the scratch untill all the task doesnt complete their execution.Plz have a look on my about algorithm .tell me it is correct or need modification?